# Dirty Memory Solution Xcode & Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, instruments

while I was improving my app in Instruments, I saw a irregular production of memory or better memory which isn't being removed.

As you can see in the screenshot the memory increases step by step. It's increasing when I push the Controller to the View, which is animating pictures.

Example:
I start in the Menu and go to the AnimationView --> memory usage is increasing.
I go back but the memory level stays the same.
When I push to the AnimationView once again --> memory level is increasing.

How can I get rid of that. I mean normally the memory has to be deleted when I quit the AnimationView

[image: Screenshot Instruments]

Best regards from Germany
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory use that grows and never drops back down is usually a sign that you are creating things and never discarding them when you are done.

I would guess that you are using storyboards, and simply invoking a new segue every time you want to display a new screen, but never popping view controllers/dismissing modals/doing unwind segues.

When you invoke a segue, iOS creates a new instance of the target view controller. Thus you can end up with an ever-increasing number of view controllers in memory, when what you meant to do was to dismiss a view controller and return to the previous view controller.

Comment: So I can use unwind segues to reduce this memory production?

Comment: Yes. You need to be aware of when you want to display a new view controller on top of the existing ones, and when you want to discard the new view controller(s) and pop back to a previous layer of your view controller stack. How do you organize and present your view controllers? Navigation Controller? Or are you just presenting a series of  modal segues?

Comment: No I use a navigationController ;)

Comment: Do I have to use the unwind segue when I quit the AnimationView or when I'm leaving the menu in direction to the AnimationView BIG THANKS !

Comment: If you use a navigation controller then you should just pop to the previous view controller.